# SpringBoot cache not working for non parameter methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I have one spring boot application

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>cachedemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cachedemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot cache</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

CacheDemoAllpication.java

```
package com.example.cachedemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class CachedemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CachedemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
package com.example.cachedemo.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.example.cachedemo.model.Book;
import com.example.cachedemo.service.LibraryService;


@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private LibraryService service;
    
    
    @RequestMapping("/get")
    public String getBooks(@RequestParam Integer id) {
        
        Book book = service.getBook(id);
        System.out.println(book);
        return book.toString();
    }
}
```

Service

```
package com.example.cachedemo.service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.cachedemo.model.Book;

@Service
public class LibraryService {

//  @Cacheable(value = "bookCache")
    public Book getBook(Integer id) {
        
        System.out.println("*******************************************Method called getBook()************************************");
        
        Map<Integer,Book> bookMap = getBookMap();
        
        return bookMap.get(id);
    }
    
    
    @Cacheable(value = "booksCache", key="#root.methodName")
    private Map<Integer,Book> getBookMap()
    {
        Book b3 = new Book(2,"Peace","Arif");
        Book b2 = new Book(3,"Mumbai City","Shiv Shankar");
        Book b1 = new Book(1,"Test","Sunny");
        
        Map<Integer,Book> bookMap = new HashMap<Integer, Book>();
        bookMap.put(1, b1);
        bookMap.put(2, b2);
        bookMap.put(3, b3);
        
        System.out.println("*******************************************Method called getBookMap()************************************");
        
        return bookMap;
    }

}
```

In the service class **getBookMap()** return a Map and I want spring to cache that. For subsequent requests it should return that map from cache. But with current setup It's not caching anything and **getBookMap()** method is being executed every time.
My first suspect was **spring-boot-starter-cache** version, but that's not the case. The behavior is same with latest version as well.

I have tried with/without **key="#root.methodName"** but the result is same.

Whereas if I cache method **getBook(Integer id)** it works just fine which gets me into thinking that no parameter methods are behaving differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. @Cacheable won't work for private methods, make your method public
2. You can't call a cacheable method from within the same class. I mean put your Cacheable method into another class and make it public. Call the method from another class. Then it'll work

Answer (score 2):

Spring uses Spring AOP to implement declarative caching (using proxies).

Annotating the `getBook` method with `@Cacheable` and calling it from the outside works as the call goes through the proxy.

You are calling `getBookMap` internally in your `LibraryService` class, that method won't go through the proxy and won't be advised , which means caching won't be triggered. Either extract the method to another class and call it from your `LibraryService` or use `AspectJ`.

Further reading: [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop)